# What is the equivalent function in meteor js for window.onload(function(){}) and $(document).ready(function(){}) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am trying to refactor jQuery code to meteor js code. Can anyone help me refactoring this part of code.

```
window.onload(function(){});
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

to meteor js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Template.myTemplate.onRendered`

> The functions added with this method are called once for every instance of Template.myTemplate when it is inserted into the page for the first time.
>
> These callbacks can be used to integrate external libraries that aren't familiar with Meteor's automatic view rendering, and need to be initialized every time HTML is inserted into the page. You can perform initialization or clean-up on any objects in onCreated and onDestroyed callbacks.

from the [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Template-onRendered)